# Strings :: Removing Parenthesis and characters inside of it

Tags: c++, string

This is my first question im sorry if I broke any rules doing so. Anyways my question is about strings. How do I delete parenthesis as well as the text inside of that in a string? for example.. I have a string "example (stuff) example". I want to be able to remove the parenthesis and the characters inside of it every time, whether its like this "(stuff) example example" or this "example example (stuff)". I am also new to c++ and am using replit as my ide and it doesnt contain an autofill feautre so I dont know what functions im working with making this task hard. If you could also point me in a direction about std::methods please let me know.

Im really new to programming and have usually received help when writing code and am now doing independent work while on break from college.

```
#include <string>

std::string remove_parentheses(const std::string &str) {
    int i = 0;
    while(i < str.length()) {
        if(str[i] == '(' || str[i] == ')' ) {
            str.erase(i,1);
        } else{i++} 
    }
    return str; // your code here
}

int main() {
    std::string str = "Computer systems";
    remove_parentheses(str);
    return 0;
}
```

it says..

> error: no matching member function for call to 'erase'
> str.erase(i,1);

input "computer (computer systems) systems"
output "computer systems"

is this not the right way to erase? I cant find the list of functions for strings or std:: functions. thanks for the help!

Comment: You can use an [online reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)

Comment: You probably know this but the algorithm is incorrect. A better approach would be to find the opening and closing parentheses first, and only then do a single erase to remove all the text you want to remove.

Comment: Nitpick, but this shouldn't compile: `else{i++}`.

Answer (score 3):

You can't erase things from a `const` reference. The `const` modifier is designed specifically to prohibit you from modifying the referent. If you want to modify it in-place, take a non-const reference.

```
void remove_parentheses(std::string &str)
```

If you want to make a new string with the modifications intact, take the string by value (incurring a copy when you call the function) and return the new string.

```
std::string remove_parentheses(std::string str)
```

Answer (score 2):

Addendum to Silvio Mayolo's answer, but I would strongly recommend outputting a new string as opposed to modifying the existing string in-place. We can use a variable to track levels of nested parentheses, and a `std::ostringstream` to efficiently build up a new string minus the parens and their contents.

```
std::string remove_parentheses(const std::string &str) {
    int paren_level = 0;
    std::ostringstream ss;

    for (auto ch : str) {
        if (ch == '(') {
            paren_level++;
        }
        else if (ch == ')' && paren_level > 0) {
            paren_level--;
        }
        else if (paren_level == 0) {
            ss << ch;
        }
    }

    return ss.str();
}
```

Taking some inspiration from rturrado's answer, but skipping C++20 and relying on C++17 features, this can be adopted to use `std::copy_if`.

```
std::string remove_parentheses(const std::string &str) {
    int paren_level = 0;
    std::string s;
    s.reserve(str.length());

    std::copy_if(str.cbegin(), str.cend(),
        std::back_inserter(s),
        [&paren_level](auto ch) {
            if (ch == '(') {
               paren_level++;
               return false;
            }
            else if (ch == ')' && paren_level > 0) {
               paren_level--;
               return false;
            }
            else if (paren_level == 0) {
               return true;
            }
        });

    return s;
}
```

Comment: Nice algorithm but since the only operation you need is to add a char to the new string, wouldn't it make sense to use an actual string instead of a ostringstream?

Comment: Using `std::string::reserve` to avoid reallocations, and then `+=` would work nicely too.

Comment: could you explain what the ss does and if you could explain parents_levels as well?

Comment: `parens_level` tracks how many levels of parens are nested. Upon encountering a `'('` it is incremented. On detecting a matching `')'` it decrements. When it's `0` we know we're outside of any (matching) parens. A stringstream allows us to build up a string efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

You can also start getting used to STL algorithms. Since C++20, you can use `std::string::erase_if`, which will basically:

- Walk every character of a string, and erase those that satisfy a condition (the size of the modified string is updated accordingly).
- The condition would be: I've found a close paren, or I have an open paren yet to close. As already explained in @Chris's answer.
- We could work on a copy of the input string, and return that copy.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/Gzzqr7778)

```cpp
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <string>

std::string remove_parentheses(std::string str) {
    int no_of_open_parens{ 0 };
    std::erase_if(str,
        [&no_of_open_parens](char c) {
            if (c == '(') {
                no_of_open_parens++;
            } else if (c == ')' and no_of_open_parens > 0) {
                no_of_open_parens--;
            }
            return c == ')' or no_of_open_parens > 0;
        }
    );
    return str;
}

int main() {
    std::string in_str = "Computer (computer systems) systems";
    auto out_str = remove_parentheses(in_str);
    std::cout << out_str << "\n";
}

// Outputs: Computer  systems
```